# I want to generate the border for this radial-gradiant and also to the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the code i have.

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5em 2em;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top center, transparent, transparent 70px, black 70px, black);
  border-radius: 8p## Heading ##x;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>

<!--  this creates the cut in a div placing a circle on the cut and i need to put a border for the whole div even in the cut part of div.  -->
```

Comment: can you clarify what you try to do ?

Comment: Judging from the comment in the code, OP is trying to get a border on the black colored containing div element. The border needs to apply only to the outer div, but also have a border that goes around the "cut" (that contains the red span), but not overlap the red span.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5em 2em;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top center, transparent, green 70px, black 70px, black);
  border-radius: 8p## Heading ##x;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid green;
}

.circle {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background-image: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/1000/1000);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="circle"></span>
</div>

<!--  this creates the cut in a div placing a circle on the cut and i need to put a border for the whole div even in the cut part of div.  -->
```